# How to replace a string in multiple files in linux command line

Tags: linux, string

I need to replace a string in a lot of files in a folder, with only `ssh` access to the server. How can I do this?

Comment: If you'd prefer to use Notepad++ instead of command line, I found this really helpful: https://superuser.com/a/1003801/74576

Answer (score 994, accepted):

```
cd /path/to/your/folder
sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' *
```

Occurrences of "foo" will be replaced with "bar".

On BSD systems like macOS, you need to provide a backup extension like `-i '.bak'` or else "risk corruption or partial content" per the manpage.

```
cd /path/to/your/folder
sed -i '.bak' 's/foo/bar/g' *
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me if the string has whitespaces or special characters in it. Any idea why that might be, or do I need to escape them some how? Thanks!

Comment: At least for my version of `sed`, `-i` requires a string after it, which is appended to the old file names. So `sed -i .bak 's/foo/bar/g' *.xx` moves all `.xx` files to the equivalent `.xx.bak` name and then generates the `.xx` files with the foo→bar substitution.

Comment: If anybody want to look for more options, there is an answer on unix stack exchange which covers more use cases site http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112024/13488

Comment: @MatthewHerbst to escape spaces, use \ like `sed -i 's/foo\ with\ spaces/bar/g' *`. I suppose you've found out after so long... but this way it stays for others finding the same issue.

Comment: I am getting this error:                                                                                                                            sed -i 's/[./(/g' *
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''

Comment: @Anaphory You can also pass in an empty string for no backups (at least on OS X). Like: `sed -i "" "s/foo/bar/g" *`

Comment: For something recursive you could try the following.  Note that it doesn't work if the list of files is huge.    `sed -i -e 's/foo/bar/g' $(find /home/user/base/dir)`

Comment: @Scot that doesn't work. `sed -i -e 's/foo/bar/g' $(find /home/user/dir)
sed: couldn't edit /home/user/dir: not a regular file`.

Comment: To get around the "not a regular file" problem, just find only files:
    `sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' $(find /path/to/your/folder -type f)`

Comment: its not working for me to replace a string like "my-syste" to ip address "10.2.5.10" getting error like "sed: 1: "filename.txt": invalid command code .". 
command i used is: find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/"dm-system7"/"10.25.98.74"/g' {} \;
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @FearlessFuture Use `**/*`, i.e. `sed -i -e 's/foo/bar/g' **/*`, where you can change it into a better match, such as `**/*.tex` for example.

Comment: not one month passes without telling myself: one day I will sit down for 2 hours and learn how to use sed... years ago I bit the bullet for vim and I never regretted it.

Comment: You can also try `rpl` (`sudo apt install rpl`)

Comment: I used `sed -i '.bak' 's/A.h/B.h/g' *` with the goal to change all ocurrences of A.h to B.h, and now there is copies of all my files with .bkk

Comment: This blog, https://victoria.dev/blog/how-to-replace-a-string-with-sed-in-current-and-recursive-subdirectories/, answers this extensively as well.

Comment: Is there a way to "test run" this?  I used option `--sandbox` but it writes the files anyway, seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 384):

Similar to Kaspar's answer but with the g flag to replace all the occurrences on a line.

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/old_string/new_string/g' {} \;
```

For global case insensitive:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/old_string/new_string/gI' {} \;
```

Ignoring `.git` directory:

```
find . -not -path '*/\.git/*' -name '*.rb'  -exec sed -i 's/old_string/new_string/g' '{}' \;
```

Comment: If you are on OSX and your patterns might contain dots and you want in-place replacement (no backup file) you should use `LC_ALL=C find ./ -type f -exec sed -i '' -e 's/proc.priv/priv/g' {} \;` (see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456518/invalid-command-code-despite-escaping-periods-using-sed) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242275/re-error-illegal-byte-sequence-on-mac-os-x))

Comment: This definitely worked for me, as it enables filtering with -name "*.js"'

Comment: A verbose option would be cool, but you can just re-grep to see if the changes were made. Note: For wildcards, try '-name "*.php"' and grep is bad with recursion and wildcards, you need to add `--include=*.whatever` with -r

Comment: Don't do this from the root of a checked-out Git repo. You might accidentally corrupt its database in `.git/`. Be sure to `cd` down to a lower level.

Comment: This should really be the correct answer, but make sure to have the space after `{}` or you'll get an error.

Comment: I just did this in my git repo and now `git status` returns: `error: bad index file sha1 signature.... fatal: index file corrupt`. What gives?

Comment: I fixed the error by doing an inverse `sed` regex. Now repo's back to normal.

Comment: This works, but not if you have special characters in the string, such as when changing a path. To get around this, us the following in the respective part of the command in this answer, `sed -i 's@old_path@new_path@g'`

Comment: It would be good if there was a way to ignore the `.git/` folder (as well as exclude other folders e.g. the ones specified in `.gitignore`) instead of having to cd to a lower level, which isn't convenient when there are lots of folders. Otherwise you could move them all into one folder and cd to that folder.

Comment: Works! But how do we see verbose output or progress?

Comment: @Shelljohn's comment above with LC_ALL=C find ./ -type f -exec sed -i '' -e 's/proc.priv/priv/g' {} \; was the only thing that worked for me on OSX

Comment: Does `./` start searching from the current directory?

Comment: @Black yes, it does

Comment: This seems to me like a better answer than the currently most upvoted one, as it is simple and clear, less prone to bugs and works recursively as it should.

Comment: Has anyone figured out how to combine the above command to something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63523300/9157799) to ignore directories (`.git/`, `node_modules/`, etc)?

Comment: This blog, https://victoria.dev/blog/how-to-replace-a-string-with-sed-in-current-and-recursive-subdirectories/, answers this extensively with solid info.

Answer (score 357):

@kev's answer is good, but only affects files in the immediate directory.The example below uses grep to recursively find files. It works for me everytime.

```
grep -rli 'old-word' * | xargs -i@ sed -i 's/old-word/new-word/g' @
```

---

Command breakdown

**grep -r**: *--recursive*, recursively read all files under each directory.
**grep -l**: *--print-with-matches*, prints the name of each file that has a match, instead of printing matching lines.
**grep -i**: *--ignore-case*.

**xargs**: transform the STDIN to arguments, follow this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/600273/682757).
**xargs -i@ ~command contains @~**: a placeholder for the argument to be used in a specific position in the **~command~**, the @ sign is a placeholder which could replaced by any string.

**sed -i**: edit files in place, **without** backups.
**sed s/regexp/replacement/**: substitute string matching **regexp** with **replacement**.
sed s/regexp/replacement/**g**: *global*, make the substitution for each match instead of only the first match.

Comment: this did not work for me, but this did:
`grep --include={*.php,*.html,*.js} -rnl './' -e "old-word" | xargs -i@ sed -i 's/old-word/new-word/g' @`

Comment: @pymarco Can you please explain this command? I don't know why you had to use xargs instead of just using sed after `|`, also, why `-i` in xargs command? I read in the manual it is deprecated and should use `-I` instead. And is `@` used as a delimiter for beginning and end for pattern?

Comment: the question is specifically for linux though.

Comment: On osx this is ok : `grep -rli 'old-word' * | xargs -I@ sed -i '' 's/2.0.0/latest/g' @`

Comment: It would be nice if you broke down some of the options (`rli`) and the `@` sign for example

Comment: I also get `sed no input files`

Comment: Works great, but be careful doing this within Git repositories. If you do this at the root, it changes files within .git, and messes up the repository (it doesn't track changes correctly anymore). So, be sure to do it in a subdirectory (e.g. `/src`).

Comment: I am using @PhilippeSultan suggestion (osx) but I have a `No such file or directory` error. Does anyone can help please? I am seaching for "5.9.0", one is found in README but replacing does not work : `sed: ../README.md:The current version is 5.9.0.: No such file or directory`

Comment: Worked like a charm

Comment: The explanation of the command can be found [here](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=grep+-rli+%27old-word%27+*+%7C+xargs+-i%40+sed+-i+%27s%2Fold-word%2Fnew-word%2Fg%27+%40).

Comment: On macOS (zsh 5.8.1), `grep -rli 'd<C-A>' * | xargs -I@ sed -i '.bak' 's/d<C-A>/z<C-A>/g' @` works. 

As @Frungi said, `-i '.bak'` is usually necessary on macOS (and other BSD) systems.

Comment: This is inefficient. First, `grep` will *read all files*, then, `sed` will do the same again. Just quickly listing all files by grep would be more efficient (as other solutions around are recommending).

Answer (score 71):

There are a few standard answers to this already listed. Generally, you can use **find** to recursively list the files and then do the operations with **sed** or **perl**.

### rpl

For most quick uses, you may find the command **rpl** is much easier to remember.

Replace `foo` with `bar` on all `.txt` files:

```
rpl -v foo bar '*.txt'
```

Simulate replacing the regex `foo.*` with `bar` in all `.txt` files recursively:

```
rpl --dry-run 'foo.*' bar '**/*.txt'
```

You'll probably need to install it (`apt-get install rpl` or similar).

### repren

However, for tougher jobs that involve regular expressions and back substitution, or file renames as well as search-and-replace, the most general and powerful tool I'm aware of is [**repren**](https://github.com/jlevy/repren), a small Python script I wrote a while back for some thornier renaming and refactoring tasks. The reasons you might prefer it are:

- Support renaming of files as well as search-and-replace on file contents.
- See changes before you commit to performing the search and replace.
- Support regular expressions with back substitution, whole words, case insensitive, and case preserving (replace foo -> bar, Foo -> Bar, FOO -> BAR) modes.
- Works with multiple replacements, including swaps (foo -> bar and bar -> foo) or sets of non-unique replacements (foo -> bar, f -> x).

To use it, `pip install repren`. [Check the README](https://github.com/jlevy/repren) for examples.

Comment: Wow, repren is excellent!  Just used it to change part of a word inside of class names, methods and variables while renaming files to match across 1,000+ C++ header and source files and it worked perfectly the first time with one command. Thank you!

Comment: Create tools, thanks for sharing!

Comment: Unfortunately seems like this is a Python 2 only tool. Any idea if this is ever getting migrated to Python 3?

Answer (score 59):

This worked for me:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/string1/string2/' {} \;
```

However, this did not: `sed -i 's/string1/string2/g' *`. Maybe "foo" was not meant to be string1 and "bar" not string2.

Comment: It is because sed treats the wildcard * differently. [abc]* means an arbitrary number of characters of the set {a, b, c}. [a-z0-9]* works similar to the wildcard *.

Comment: On OSX use: `find ./ -type f -exec sed -i '' -e 's/string1/string2/' {} \;`

Answer (score 39):

**To replace a string in multiple files you can use:**

```
grep -rl string1 somedir/ | xargs sed -i 's/string1/string2/g'
```

E.g.

```
grep -rl 'windows' ./ | xargs sed -i 's/windows/linux/g'
```

[Source blog](http://vasir.net/blog/ubuntu/replace_string_in_multiple_files)

Answer (score 35):

Given you want to search for the string `search` and replace it with `replace` across multiple files, this is [my battle-tested, one-line formula](https://www.internalpointers.com/post/linux-find-and-replace-text-multiple-files):

```
grep -RiIl 'search' | xargs sed -i 's/search/replace/g'
```

Quick grep explanation:

- `-R` - recursive search
- `-i` - case-insensitive
- `-I` - skip binary files (you want text, right?)
- `-l` - print a simple list as output. Needed for the other commands

The grep output is then piped to sed (through xargs) which is used to actually replace text. The `-i` flag will alter the file directly. Remove it for a kind of "dry run" mode.

Comment: If the text happens to be a url, remember you use different delimiters with sed ike this: 's#search#replace#g'

Comment: When using `grep -i` for case-insensitive search, you also need to let sed do its own search in a case-insensitive way. For that, replace the sed command with `sed -i 's/search/replace/gI'`.

Comment: I think this breaks when a file name contains a 'newline' character.

Answer (score 34):

To replace a path within files (avoiding escape characters) you may use the following command:

```
sed -i 's@old_path@new_path@g'
```

The @ sign means that all of the special characters should be ignored in a following string.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for in all the other answers.  Namely, how to deal with special characters, such as when changing a string that is a path. Thank you. Seemed like a big oversight in the other answers.

Answer (score 25):

In case your string has a forward slash(/) in it, you could change the delimiter to '+'.

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's+http://example.com+https://example.com+g' {} +
```

This command would run recursively in the current directory.

Comment: Thanks! Helped change a load of references of `../domain.com` to `domain.com`

Answer (score 13):

If you have list of files you can use

```
replace "old_string" "new_string" -- file_name1 file_name2 file_name3
```

If you have all files you can use

```
replace "old_string" "new_string" -- *
```

If you have list of files with extension, you can use

```
replace "old_string" "new_string" -- *.extension
```

Comment: actually, "--file" should just be "--", at least in my version

Comment: This utility is distributed within MySQL packages.

Comment: Though I would like to appreciate solution, which works without quoting regular line to be regular expression.

Comment: This works fine - and if you want to replace all strings in multiple files, which end in  e.g. ".txt" , you can just do `replace "old_string" "new_string" -- *.txt `

Comment: How do you include subdirectories of one specific directory?

Comment: It's better to add from where to get this `replace` utility. Without this information, this answer is incomplete.

Comment: They would have done better to distribute this utility separately. Anyway, I’ve found the `rpl` utility, which _can_ be installed separately on Debian-based distros, to be an adequate alternative.

Answer (score 12):

"You could also use find and sed, but I find that this little line of perl works nicely.

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/search/replace/g;' *.php
```

- -e means execute the following line of code.
- -i means edit in-place
- -w write warnings
- -p loop

" (Extracted from http://www.liamdelahunty.com/tips/linux_search_and_replace_multiple_files.php)

My best results come from using perl and grep (to ensure that file have the search expression )

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/search/replace/g;' $( grep -rl 'search' )
```

Comment: I prefer this as its cross-platform with no effort between Mac/Linux

Answer (score 12):

The first line occurrences of "foo" will be replaced with "bar". And you can using the second line to check.

```
grep -rl 'foo' . | xargs sed -i 's/foo/bar/g'
grep 'foo' -r * | awk -F: {'print $1'} | sort -n | uniq -c
```

Comment: Why are you linking to to your blog? It contains exactly the same text as your answer.

Comment: i like `grep -rl 'foo' . | xargs sed -i 's/foo/bar/g'`

Answer (score 6):

On a MacBook Pro, I used the following (inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/19457213/6169225):

```
sed -i '' -e 's/<STR_TO_REPLACE>/<REPLACEMENT_STR>/g' *
```

> `-i ''` will ensure you are taking no backups.
>
> `-e` for modern regex.

Comment: `-e` just tells sed that the next token is a command. For extended regular expressions, use `-E` instead.

Answer (score 5):

I did concoct my own solution before I found this question (and answers).
I searched for different combinations of "replace" "several" and "xml," because that was my application, but did not find this particular one.

My problem: I had spring xml files with data for test cases, containing complex objects. A refactor on the java source code changed a lot of classes and did not apply to the xml data files. In order to save the test cases data, I needed to change all the class names in all the xml files, distributed across several directories. All while saving backup copies of the original xml files (although this was not a must, since version control would save me here).

I was looking for some combination of `find` + `sed`, because it worked for me in other situations, but not with several replacements at once.

Then I found [ask ubuntu response](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84007/find-and-replace-text-within-multiple-files) and it helped me build my command line:

```
find -name "*.xml" -exec sed -s --in-place=.bak -e 's/firstWord/newFirstWord/g;s/secondWord/newSecondWord/g;s/thirdWord/newThirdWord/g' {} \;
```

And it worked perfectly (well, my case had six different replacements). But please note that it will touch all *.xml files under current directory. Because of that, and if you are accountable to a version control system, you might want to filter first and only pass on to `sed` those actually having the strings you want; like:

```
find -name "*.xml" -exec grep -e "firstWord" -e "secondWord" -e "thirdWord" {} \; -exec sed -s --in-place=.bak -e 's/firstWord/newFirstWord/g;s/secondWord/newSecondWord/g;s/thirdWord/newThirdWord/g' {} \;
```

Comment: and for windows, I just found out that there is a way to find the string --didn't check yet how to replace it-- in one command:

`findstr /spin /c:"quéquieresbuscar" *.xml`

It will be handy.

Answer (score 5):

Really lame, but I couldn't get any of the sed commands to work right on OSX, so I did this dumb thing instead:

```
:%s/foo/bar/g
:wn
```

^- copy these three lines into my clipboard (yes, include the ending newline), then:

vi *

and hold down command-v until it says there's no files left.

Dumb...hacky...effective...

Answer (score 4):

```
grep --include={*.php,*.html} -rnl './' -e "old" | xargs -i@ sed -i 's/old/new/g' @
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd just like to add a note to do two things at once - find a file that contains a string and then do a replace, using the find 'chaining' method:

```
find  . -type f -iname \*.php -exec fgrep -l "www." {} \; -exec sed -i "s|www||g" {} \;
```

- In this real case, remove the anachronistic 'www' from urls found in PHP files.
- The 'fgrep -l' only triggers if it finds at least one match in a file, it produces no other output. Don't forget the '\;' separators!

Answer (score 3):

**script for multiedit command**

```
multiedit [-n PATTERN] OLDSTRING NEWSTRING
```

From Kaspar's answer I made a bash script to accept command line arguments and optionally limit the filenames matching a pattern. Save in your $PATH and make executable, then just use the command above.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
_help="\n
Replace OLDSTRING with NEWSTRING recursively starting from current directory\n
multiedit [-n PATTERN] OLDSTRING NEWSTRING\n

[-n PATTERN] option limits to filenames matching PATTERN\n
Note: backslash escape special characters\n
Note: enclose STRINGS with spaces in double quotes\n
Example to limit the edit to python files:\n
multiedit -n \*.py \"OLD STRING\" NEWSTRING\n"

# ensure correct number of arguments, otherwise display help...
if [ $# -lt 2 ] || [ $# -gt 4 ]; then echo -e $_help ; exit ; fi
if [ $1 == "-n" ]; then  # if -n option is given:
        # replace OLDSTRING with NEWSTRING recursively in files matching PATTERN
        find ./ -type f -name "$2" -exec sed -i "s/$3/$4/g" {} \;
else
        # replace OLDSTRING with NEWSTRING recursively in all files
        find ./ -type f -exec sed -i "s/$1/$2/" {} \;
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

The stream editor does modify multiple files “inplace” when invoked with the `-i` switch, which takes a backup file ending as argument. So

```
sed -i.bak 's/foo/bar/g' *
```

replaces `foo` with `bar` in all files in this folder, but does not descend into subfolders. This will however generate a new `.bak` file for every file in your directory.
To do this recursively for all files in this directory and all its subdirectories, you need a helper, like `find`, to traverse the directory tree.

```
find ./ -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i.bak 's/foo/bar/g' *
```

`find` allows you further restrictions on what files to modify, by specifying further arguments like `find ./ -name '*.php' -or -name '*.html' -print0`, if necessary.

---

Note: GNU `sed` does not require a file ending, `sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' *` will work, as well; FreeBSD `sed` demands an extension, but allows a space in between, so `sed -i .bak s/foo/bar/g *` works.

Answer (score 2):

To maintain my personal English node, I wrote an utility script that help to replace multiple pair of old/new string, for all files under a directory recursively.

The multiple pair of old / new string are managed in a hash map.

The dir can be set via command line or environment variable, the map is hard coded in the script, but you can modify the code to load from a file, if necessary.

It requires bash 4.2, due to some new feature.

**en_standardize.sh:**

```
#! /bin/bash
# (need bash 4.2+,)
# 
# Standardize phonetic symbol of English.
# 
# format:
#   en_standardize.sh [<dir>]
# 
# params:
# * dir
#   target dir, optional,
#   if not specified then use environment variable "$node_dir_en",
#   if both not provided, then will not execute,
# * 
# 

paramCount=$#

# figure target dir,
if [ $paramCount -ge 1 ]; then # dir specified
    echo -e "dir specified (in command):\n\t$1\n"
    targetDir=$1
elif [[ -v node_dir_en ]]; then # environable set,
    echo -e "dir specified (in environment vairable):\n\t$node_dir_en\n"
    targetDir=$node_dir_en
else # environable not set,
    echo "dir not specified, won't execute"
    exit
fi

# check whether dir exists,
if [ -d $targetDir ]; then
    cd $targetDir
else
    echo -e "invalid dir location:\n\t$targetDir\n"
    exit
fi

# initial map,
declare -A itemMap
itemMap=( ["ɪ"]="i" ["ː"]=":" ["ɜ"]="ə" ["ɒ"]="ɔ" ["ʊ"]="u" ["ɛ"]="e")

# print item maps,
echo 'maps:'
for key in "${!itemMap[@]}"; do
    echo -e "\t$key\t->\t${itemMap[$key]}"
done
echo -e '\n'

# do replace,
for key in "${!itemMap[@]}"; do
    grep -rli "$key" * | xargs -i@ sed -i "s/$key/${itemMap[$key]}/g" @
done

echo -e "\nDone."
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

If the file contains backslashes (paths usually) you can try something like this:

```
sed -i -- 's,<path1>,<path2>,g' *
```

ex:

```
sed -i -- 's,/foo/bar,/new/foo/bar,g' *.sh (in all shell scripts available)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this one from another post (can't remember which) and while not the most elegant, it's simple and as a novice Linux user has given me no trouble

```
for i in *old_str* ; do mv -v "$i" "${i/\old_str/new_str}" ; done
```

if you have spaces or other special characters use a \

```
for i in *old_str\ * ; do mv -v "$i" "${i/\old_str\ /new_str}" ; done
```

for strings in sub-directories use **

```
for i in *\*old_str\ * ; do mv -v "$i" "${i/\old_str\ /new_str}" ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the ack command would be alot faster like this:

```
ack '25 Essex' -l | xargs sed -i 's/The\ fox \jump/abc 321/g'
```

Also if you have a white space in the search result. You need to escape it.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way by using a simple script file:

```
   # sudo chmod +x /bin/replace_string_files_present_dir
```

open the file in gedit or an editor of your choice, I use gedit here.

```
   # sudo gedit /bin/replace_string_files_present_dir
```

Then in the editor paste the following in the file

```
   #!/bin/bash
   replace "oldstring" "newstring" -- *
   replace "oldstring1" "newstring2" -- *
   #add as many lines of replace as there are your strings to be replaced for 
   #example here i have two sets of strings to replace which are oldstring and 
   #oldstring1 so I use two replace lines.
```

Save the file, close **gedit**, then exit your terminal or just close it and then start it to be able load the new script you added.

Navigate to the directory where you have multiple files you want to edit. Then run:

```
  #replace_string_files_present_dir
```

Press enter and this will automatically replace the **oldstring** and **oldstring1** in all the files that contain them with the correct **newstring** and **newstring1** respectively.

It will skip all the directories and files that don't contain the old strings.

This might help in eliminating the tedious work of typing in case you have multiple directories with files that need string replacement. All you have to do is navigate to each of those directories, then run:

`#replace_string_files_present_dir`

All you have to do is to ensure you've included or added all the replacement strings as I showed you above:

`replace "oldstring" "newstring" -- *`

at the end of the file **/bin/replace_string_files_present_dir**.

To add a new replace string just open the script we created by typing the following in the terminal:

`sudo gedit /bin/replace_string_files_present_dir`

Don't worry about the number of replace strings you add, they will have no effect if the **oldstring** is not found.

Comment: Usually, when people ask "how to ${whatever}" in bash, they are asking for a compact version to include in a script or **CI jobs** instruction (say a `.gitlab-ci.yml` or a `travis.yml`). Every turn around consisting in writing a script to execute it later is an anti-pattern, for you'll then need to  script the script creation (and I goes messy, most of the time)

Comment: @zar3bski wut? You really should be putting your individual CI steps in separate shell files so that they are portable to other CI systems. It also makes them testable locally.

Answer (score 0):

Below command can be used to first search the files and replace the files:

```
find . | xargs grep 'search string' | sed 's/search string/new string/g'
```

For example

```
find . | xargs grep abc | sed 's/abc/xyz/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am giving an example for fixing a common shebang error in python sources.

You can try the grep/sed approach. Here is one that works with GNU sed and won't break a git repo:

```
$ grep -rli --exclude '*.git*' '#!/usr/bin/python' . | xargs -I {} \
gsed -i '' -e 's/#!\/usr\/bin\/python/#!\/usr\/bin\/env python/' {}
```

Or you can use [greptile](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Greptile) :)

```
$ greptile -x .py -l -i -g '#!/usr/bin/env python' -r '#!/usr/bin/python' .
```

I just tested the first script, and the second should work as well. Be careful with escape characters, I think it should be easier to use greptile in most cases. Of course, you can do many interesting things with sed, and for that it may be preferable to master using it with xargs.

Answer (score 0):

My problem with many of the answers was that I needed to replace a filepath inside of many files. Though one answer provided mentioned this, it did not work for me. My solution:

First, generate a list of the filenames that you want to be changed.

```sh
filelist=($(find /path/to/your/folder | xargs grep '/path/to/fix' | cut -d : -f 1 | tr '\n' ' '))
```

What the commands above do is that the `find` piped to `grep` generates the names of the files with the `/path/to/fix` inside. However, `grep` also prints out the line that the string was found on, so the `cut` command gets rid of this and just keeps the filename. `tr` replaces newline characters with spaces, which allows for `filelist` to be stored as an array.

```sh
for file in "${filelist[@]}"; do sed -i.bak 's+/path/to/fix+/new/path/for/my/file+g' $file; done
```

This `sed` command draws on other answers to this question, and uses `+` as delimiters rather than the normal `/`, since the `/` characters are being used in the filepath.

Comment: You can use `grep -l` to get rid of the `cut` and `-m1` to speed it up. If you are not recursing directories here, you didn't need the `find` either. The `tr` can be avoided by setting `IFS` to newline. It will also fail on filenames with spaces. So, simplified: `IFS=$'\n' filelist=($(grep -IRlim1 'path/to/fix' .) )`. But the other find+sed answers already work fine for paths as long as you use a different delimiter, like you did with '+'.

Answer (score 0):

I used `ag`, the_silver_searcher:

```
ag -0 -l 'old' | xargs -0 sed -ri.bak -e 's/old/new/g';
```

Then `git clean` to remove .bak files (`rm` was being buggy when running inside a git rebase `exec`)

```
git clean -f '**/*.bak';
```

Answer (score -1):

I like the following to replace the string to replace with nothing in the example below:

```
for file in /path/to/your/files/*.txt; do
  sed -i '' 's/string to replace/ /g' "$file"
done
```

but you can also do

```
for file in /path/to/your/files/*; do
  sed -i '' 's/oldstring/newstring/g' "$file"
done
```