# How to rename an Angular project?

Tags: angular

I renamed my Angular 4 project folder from **auction-life** to **auction-05-life** and replaced 3 occurrences of the old project name in:

- angular-cli.json Line 4
- app.e2e-spec.ts Line 3
- package.json Line 2

I then ran `ng serve` and got this:

> You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core". This is an error.

**Edit:** Following the instructions in the comments below, I restarted the terminal window, ensured I was in the correct project folder **auction-05-life**, ran `npm install` then `ng serve` and this time got a different exception:

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'heimdalljs-logger'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
...
```

Comment: Tried `./node_modules/.bin/ng serve` ?

Comment: I doubt with three occurrences  of the old project name sentence.

Comment: Are you sure you're in the correct folder when you run `ng serve`, where `@angular/core` is installed in `node_modules` and is present in `node_modules`?

Comment: Restart the terminal window

Comment: You seem to have somewhere a hardcoded path. Look for that. Otherwise, as you said you have the option to: remove all node-modules, uninstall angular-cli (instructions are on angular cli page, very useful) it.  And run npm install and install angular-cli again.

Answer (score 40):

1. Search in your project wherever the old name is used.
2. In Visual Studio Code search can be done by using the search bar provided.
3. Replace old name with your new name.
4. Rename the project folder name as well and you are done.
5. If some error occurs while running your project , delete the node_modules and 
   do "npm install".Everything will be fine and running again.

Comment: Does the folder name have to be the same as the project name?

Comment: @Neville not necessarily but is common practice.

Comment: Warning: while replacing, you may also replace other data/code if the name is same as project name. check @Reza 's answer.

Answer (score 39):

1. Modify Project name in `angular.json` file (Replace all occurrences of the old name in `angular.json`)
2. Rename Project folder name.
3. Delete `node_modules` folder from your project directory.
4. Run `npm install` command.
5. Finally run `ng serve` command.

Comment: much easier and cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: This is the proper answer

Comment: In my case deleting the `package-lock.json` following this tuto(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T7ef0bOOWs4) helped me

Comment: That is the correct answer @Reza but also do not forget the "README.md" file contents also   

Answer (score 14):

As of this writing, the Angular-cli commandline doesn't do renaming.
So, this is what i did (manually):

**1**. First, see how really invested the old name is in the project by searching the "old name". On Linux, i used simple grep as.

```
grep -ir "oldname" .
```

That showed so many files, most of them under /node_modules. So i removed the /node_modules (and will use npm install after i finish the rename).

**2**. Next, i did Linux find & replace command against the files in current folder as follows (source sited at bottom):

```
cd your folder
sed -i 's/oldName/newName/g' *
```

Finally, don’t forget to do ***npm install*** on the current directory to install dependencies listed in your package.json (remember we removed node_modules that had old name)

** Credits:

Find replace "sed" command is from: 
[How to replace a string in multiple files in linux command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392478/how-to-replace-a-string-in-multiple-files-in-linux-command-line)

Comment: The idea was very helpful. Unfortunately, it was not enough. The search and replace under Linux could not capture all the files. I still had to use the search & replace function in VSCode to replace most of the files. Somehow the old name was still found in the package.json, which I had to change manually. Note: To optimize the search process, remove the node_modules folder first. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

```
1. Open your project directory with "Visual Studio Code"
2. Usually Ctrl+Shift+H enter "old project name" and replace "new project name" it everywhere Ctrl+Alt+Enter.
3. Delete "node_modules" folder from your project directory.
4. Rename project folder name to "new project name".
5. Run "npm install" command.

Finally run "ng serve" command.
```

Comment: Why it is required to delete node_modules folder? It has no reference with project name or it does?

Comment: To clean up and make sure there are no errors while running your project. @VimalPatel

Answer (score 2):

With macOS you go to your angular project folder,
and use sed command to replace old name by the new that you want:

```
LC_CTYPE=C && LANG=C && find * -type f -exec sed -i "" "s/old-angular-project-name/new-name/g" {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiar with bash scripting but with your IDE, you always can perform recursive search in your files (usually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) and replace it everywhere - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on VSCode.
[Visual Studio Code Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoUOq.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the last version of Angular (13 ) no use of the Project name in the code so to change the Project folder name you need only to change the name of the folder and run you app is like this.

Comment: angular.json still references the Project Name in multiple configurations such as outputpath, defaultProject and browserTarget