# Renaming an Angular project safely?

Tags: angular, rename

I need to rename a Angular 8 project from bottom to top: The folder name and every line of code using the original project name I gave.

I saw from former posts (and former angular versions) that there was no CLI commande for it. Is it still true ?

Any method/advice on how to do it ?

Bertrand

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rename an Angular project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45891832/how-to-rename-an-angular-project)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no cli command to rename your Project.

If you want to rename it, you have to find all the places where your  current Projectname is used and change the name.

Here is a link to the a similar question:
[How to rename an Angular project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45891832/how-to-rename-an-angular-project)

Good luck!