# replace a line in files present in different folders shell script

Tags: shell, sed

I have a common line in different files present in different folders. how can i replace that line with some other line using `shell script` sed command in all the files of the folders ?

**Eg: t="/home/file.txt"** present in one of the file in a folder
same line is present in different file of differnt folder

I have to replace it with **t="/desk/file1.txt"** . so where can i execute the `sed` command whether outside the folder ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace a string in multiple files in linux command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392478/how-to-replace-a-string-in-multiple-files-in-linux-command-line)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! There are a few ways you could do this, but StackOverflow is about helping you fix your own code, we're not a free consultancy and coding service. Try to solve your own problem, and if/when you run into difficulty, that's the time to ask a question. Please add your attempt, and your results, to your question. Only then can we help you figure out where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/strng1/string2/g' {} +
```

**string1** will be replaced by **string2**. It will replace all the files in the current directory and its all subdirectories.  You need to run this script from parent directory

If you want to work this with both **GNU** and **BSD/Mac**, use this

```
 find . -type f -exec sed -i.bak 's/strng1/string2/g' {} +
```

Comment: when i tried this it is asking for input( >). it does not get executed .please help

Comment: This use of the `-i` option for `sed` will work in GNU sed, common on Linux, but not in other variants (*BSD, macOS, Solaris, etc, etc). If the question isn't platform specific but your solution is, it's a good idea to point that out to reduce confusion. Or better yet, suggest a portable solution.

Comment: @ ghoti, Thanks for this info.