# How to replace specific text occurrences in multiple .mac files

Tags: batch-file, replace, terminal

I want to replace a specific occurence of the word "Metal" in a number of .mac-files. As far as I saw these are text files.

**First example file:**

> Size    : 24mm 1547856 Metal
>   Colour   : red
>   Number   : 1547856 Metal

**Second example file:**

> Size    : 26mm 2658915 Metal
>   Colour   : blue
>   Number   : 2658915 Metal

I want to replace `Number   : 1547856 Metal` with `Number   : 1547856 Steel` in the first file and `Number   : 2658915 Metal` with `Number   : 2658915 Steel` in the second file, but I don't want the *"Metal"* in the first line to be replaced.

I tried doing it with the the following code via Terminal, but it replaces all occurences of *"Metal"* in the files:

```
maccmd /replace "Metal" "Steel"
```

**How can I replace only the *"Metal"* in the line that starts with *"Number"* without replacing any other occurence of *"Metal"* in the file?**

I don't know anything about the maccmd program. So I am fine with a simple windows batch program.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a native shell and be able to use sed and awk?

Comment: Thanks Max Vollmer thats very friendly!

Comment: You might want to look into regular expressions. I can't post a full answer right now, but if that `/replace` command allows regular expressions, it should be fairly easy. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392478/how-to-replace-a-string-in-multiple-files-in-linux-command-line) might help.

Comment: @MaxVollmer I need this for the windows terminal, because I have .mac-files on a windows pc.I can not install a unix shell

Comment: @aschipfl I only have windows terminal

Comment: Ah, okay, sorry for the misunderstanding!

Answer (score 1):

found a solution with PowerShell, but it is only working for text files.

```
$find="world"
$replace="nice"
$path="path to folder"
$position=0

Get-ChildItem $path -Filter * | 
Foreach-Object {
    $file = $_.FullName

    $string=Get-Content $file -Raw
    $pos=$string.IndexOf($find, $string.IndexOf($find)+$position)


  if ($pos -ne -1)
  {
      "{0}{1}{2}" -f $string.Substring(0, $pos), $replace, $string.Substring($pos + $find.Length) | Out-File -filepath $file 
  } else {
     $string | Out-File -filepath $file 
  }

}
```

Comment: This program only works for text files. When I try to do it with my .mac files, I can't open afterwards. Does anyone have a idea what I can try to do to handle it with .mac files?

Comment: What is a `.mac` file? I guess it is a text file using a particular encoding and/or line-break style, so please tell us...

Answer (score 0):

The following [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) (let us call it `replac.bat`) works only if the text file does not contain `||`, if DOS-/Windows- or Unix-style line-breaks (CR + LF or LF, respectively) are used and if the encoding is ASCII-/ANSI-text:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~1"    & rem // (file to process; use first command line argument)
set "_FIND=Number" & rem // (string at beginning of lines to find lines to process)
set "_SRCH=Metal"  & rem // (string at end of lines to be replaced)
set "_REPL=Steel"  & rem // (string to replace found string at end of lines)

for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "%_FILE%"') do (
    for /F "tokens=1-2 delims=: " %%I in ("%%L") do (
        set "LINE=%%L" & set "ITEM=%%J"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "EXCH=!LINE!||" & set "EXCH=!EXCH:%_SRCH%||=%_REPL%||!" & set "EXCH=!EXCH:||=!"
        if "!ITEM!"=="%_FIND%" (
            echo(!EXCH:*:=!
        ) else (
            echo(!LINE:*:=!
        )
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

The text file (let us assume `sample.txt`) must be given as a command line argument, like this:

```cmd
replac.bat "sample.txt"
```

To write the output to a different file (let us assume `return.txt`) use redirection, like this:

```cmd
replac.bat "sample.txt" > "return.txt"
```