# How to replace a string in multiple files in multiple subfolders with different file extensions in linux using command line

Tags: linux, string

I have already followed this query @ ([How to replace a string in multiple files in linux command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392478/how-to-replace-a-string-in-multiple-files-in-linux-command-line/20721292#20721292)).

My question is rather an extension of the same.

I want to check only specific file extensions in the subfolders also but not every file extension.

What I have already tried:

```
grep -rli 'old-word' * | xargs -i@ sed -i 's/old-word/new-word/g' @
```

My problem: It is changing in every other file format as well. I want to search and replace only in one file extension.

Please add another answer where I can change the entire line of a file as well not just one word.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is interesting one-line command solution that should solve problems like Yours

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.cpp" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l 'searchedString' | tee /dev/tty | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 sed -i 's/searchedString/replacementString/g'
```

Advantages:

- this command correctly handles file names with whitespaces and special characters
- it is possible to precisely filter which files need to be searched and which shouldn't using find expressions
- grep does additional filtering from these found files to select only files among them which contain searched string
- this command also writes out to console window which filtered files have been modified in the end (optionally can write this information to some log file)
- it searches recursively all subdirectories from specified directory

I couldn't quite find a similar solution which does simultaneously all above in other threads on this topic

Explanation:

- `./` - start searching in current directory. This can be replaced by any directory in file system
- `-type f` - search only for files (not directories, etc.)
- `-print0` - append null character to the end of each found file name. Important for piping the output to `xargs -0`
- `xargs -0` - treat input as a serie of strings ending with null character and pass it to the next grep command. This is important to correctly handle file names with whitespaces and special characters
- `grep -l 'searchedString'` - filter input files to output only file names that contain searchedString. -l causes output to contain only filenames instead of matched lines in files so that they can be accepted as input for sed
- `tee /dev/tty` - this does the fork of grep output to next command in pipeline and also to /dev/tty which is the console window to see what files are going to be changed. Optionally can write this information to some log file instead like that: `... | tee ~/replacement.log | tr ...`
- `tr '\n' '\0'` - by default grep -l outputs file names separated with new lines. So tr does translation/replacement of newlines with null characters for input for xargs -0 to avoid whitespaces/special characters problem
- `sed -i` - `i` parameter tells sed to make changes "in-place", that is to modify files provided as argument not just write modified content in console window instead
- `'s/searchedString/replacementString/g'` - s stands for substitution/replacement, g - stands for global, that is replacing all occurrences in a line not only first occurrence in a line

Example:

replacing all occurrences of the phrase `parameter_extraction` with `ParameterExtraction` in all .cpp and .c files but not the .c, .cpp files that have been appended _old in the file names like test_old.cpp

```
find ./ -type f \( \( -name "*.cpp" -o -iname "*.c" \) -a -not -iname "*_old.*" \) -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l 'parameter_extraction' | tee /dev/tty | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 sed -i 's/parameter_extraction/ParameterExtraction/g'
```

In find expressions:
`-o` stands for logical or
`-a` stands for logical and
note: it is important to add a space after expression opening brackets \( and before ending brackets \) otherwise there will be an error

You also asked how to change the entire lines in a file, not just one phrase
The way to do that is to use modified sed command

If You want to replace whole lines with new different lines only when input lines contain the searched phrase You can use sed with different syntax
c - stands for cut, that is to put a replacementString in place of lines that contained searchedString

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.cpp" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l 'searchedString' | tee /dev/tty | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 sed -i '/searchedString/c replacementLine'
```

Or if You want to replace whole matched lines with new different lines You can use regex symbols ^ and $
^ - denotes start of the line before the next symbol
$ - denotes end of the line after the previous symbol
So whole lines can be matched with ^line$ regex phrase

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.cpp" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l '^searchedLine$' | tee /dev/tty | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 sed -i 's/^searchedLine$/replacementLine/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Simplest solution is to use complex `grep` command:

   grep -rli --include="*.html" --include=".json" 'old-word' *

The disadvantage of this solution. Is that you do not have clear control which files are scanned.

2. Better suggesting to tune a `find` command to locate your desired files.

Using RegExp filtering option `-regex` to filter file names.

So you verify the correct files are scanned.

Than feed the `find` command result to `grep` scanning list.

#### Example:

Assuming you are looking for file extensions `txt` `pdf` `html` .

Assuming your search path begins in `/home/user/data`

```
 find /home/user/data -regex ".*\.\(html\|txt\|pdf\)$"
```

Once you have located your files. It is possible to `grep` match each file from the the above `find` command:

```
 grep -rli 'old-word' $( find /home/user/data -regex ".*\.\(html\|txt\|pdf\)$" )
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope someone will take advantage of this coding line even if the answer or solution is too,late.
this is the command line that always works for me.

```
find ./ -type f | xargs sed -i 's/old-word/new-word/g'
```

Enjoy. :)